# Django: CSS is not getting applied

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have placed all my CSS files in `static/css` folder. My settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

While the media files are working properly, and the images kept in `static/images` folder are also appearing, the CSS styling are not appearing. For each page, I am creating a CSS file, placing that in `static/css` folder, and calling it like this:

```
{% load static %}
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/getting-started.css' %}"> <--this
</head>
```

The `getting-started.css` file:

```
h3{
  text-align: left;
}

p {
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

Though the `bootstrap.min.css` is working, the CSS are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving full path in `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]`

For example `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/static')]`

In my case my app name was accounts and then static folder inside it.

Comment: Thanks, but I've placed `static` in the project directory.

Comment: Try creating a folder in base directory with name staticfiles and then run `manage.py collectstatic`. First add `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your-project-name/staticfiles')` in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

You have to collect all staticfiles before loading them in your template:

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Did that, `STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'`. But it still isn't working. Could it be that bootstrap is overwriting its setting over CSS? (Naive point.)

Comment: No, I don't think so. Try instead STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'your_project_name/static_cdn' then collect. so you should see where all the staticfiles are going and can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing turning DEBUG=False , try to check out this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#deployment.

If you are developing turning DEBUG=True , and still having trouble , follow below methods .

1. Create a folder inside static folder withyour app name . Move  folder css to this location and update the href such that new href = "{% static 'appname/css/getting-started.css' %}"

After that update the settings to

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Below code is only needed your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

You can refer : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

2. Check whether the css file is loaded by inspecting the rendered element using the inspect element so that you can verify whether it is loaded . The css styling you used might be not matching with elements in the html . If it is loaded you can view your below code

```
h3{
 text-align: left;
}

p {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 20px;
}
```